# Selecting n% rows in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a set of around 50k numbers in my table. I want to split or fetch a certain percentage of rows. I'm using DB2, so I can't use the `top` clause like in MS SQL Server.

Earlier I was using `limit` as I needed to select n rows.

```
Select subs_msisdn 
from DB2.table
Limit 10
```

But now I need to select n percent of rows instead of n rows. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use the `OFFSET` and `FETCH FIRST` clauses in DB2 to select a certain number of percentage of rows from your data table of database.

Comment: If I'm right, DB2 provides "FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY". So if you need for example 20% of your table, one way would be execute select count(*) * 0.2 from yourtable as a variable or cte and put the result in the FECTCH FIRST condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the **exact** percentage of the rows to be returned, and if your Db2 version supports it, you can use the [`TABLESAMPLE` clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=clause-table-reference#sdx-synid_frag-tablesample-clause)

```
Select subs_msisdn from DB2.table tablesample system(10)
```